# how can I determine the encryption settings of an RDP session?

Tags: remote-desktop, encryption, ssl

We have a new client who is having us connect to their Server remotely via RDP without the use of a VPN Tunnel.

I have been asked to confirm that the connection will be encrypted (HIPAA).  Unfortunately, I do not have access to check the Server group policy settings.  How would I determine what type of encryption is being used from our user's side?

Comment: If you have neither real control over the client nor the server the only option I see is looking at the network traffic e.g. using Wireshark. Wireshark should have a matching dissector for the RDP protocol so you may be able to check what connection is established.